# reset / clear all text box function not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that is supposed to clear/reset all textbox in my aspx.page and this page is using a master page but it doesn't work. below is the code. Just got this code from this site.

```
//Clear all textbox

ResetTextBoxes(this);

//function to clear textboxes
    private void ResetTextBoxes(Control parent)
        {
            if (parent is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)parent).Text = string.Empty;
            }

        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (child is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)child).Text = string.Empty;
            }

            ResetTextBoxes(child);
        }

    }
```

Comment: And how are you calling ResetTextBoxes and what is this in that context?

Comment: (this) is the Page that contains the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to share a solution on asp.net codebehind. In this , you should put all the id's of your textboxes in array.

```
     TextBox[] textboxes = {TextBox2,TextBox3,TextBox4,TextBox5,TextBox6 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        TextBox myTextBox = textboxes[i];
        myTextBox.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: wow! it works! thanks man! I didn't think it could be done by putting the id's in an array and access them via index. hahaha. anyways, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The other way around I found is use a javascript function that will clear all my asp.net Textboxes. I've added a class to all all the Textbox e.g.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" class="mTxtBox">  </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" class="mTxtBox">  </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDept" runat="server" class="mTxtBox">  </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button onclick="ClearTxtBoxes_Click" ID="ClearTxtBoxes" runat="server" Text="Clear Fields"> </asp:Button>
```

//onclick event of Button

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"runJs","clearText();",true);
```

//my JavaScriptFunction

```
    function clearText(){
     $('.mTxtBox').val('');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Controls sometimes have a hard time updating. Try calling `child.Refresh();` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: in what part of my code should i use child.Refresh?